# Text encoding not working properly on execution

Tags: java, intellij-idea, encoding, utf-8

I've been working for some time on my current project with Java (1.8.0_31) in IntelliJ IDEA (15.0.1 for Windows x64), where I use some text lines with special characters (e.g. "ó"). It has been working so far with no issue, but today it won't.

To put it short, I have a code line like this:

```
System.out.println("ó");
```

which has been outputting this (expected):

```
ó
```

Today, the output with the same source code is (unexpected):

```
Ã³
```

Code files are encoded in UTF-8 and the editor is setup accordingly. AFAIK, I've changed nothing.

I've created a brand new project to test this and it worked properly, so it may be something related specifically with my project.

Any idea about how to solve this?

Comment: This happens when javac compiler and editor(s) diverge on the encoding. It could be some component, like a style checker/version control after-burner that took the document in core, and wrote a "corrected" version to disk. However the first would be to look for your config: when using maven, validate the pom.xml and compare it. Is there somewhere a `-Dfile.encoding=` or `System.setProperty("file.encoding", "...");`?

Comment: `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`returns "UTF-8".

Comment: If that is also the code of the java source text, then all would be fine. Then you _might_ see `Ã³`` in the console, when running on Windows, that in general does not use UTF-8 but some single byte encoding like Windows-1252. The Operating System then simply cannot handle that. Maybe someone added a --Dfile.encoding yesterday?

Comment: I'm the only programmer on this project and I didn't add such line. It doesn't affect only the console, but string literals I'm using for system paths, which is the real problem here.

The source text is UTF-8 as well, (checked with IDEA and Notepad++).

If I recode the file to ANSI it works like a charm, although that is not what I want, obviously.

There something weird going on here...

Comment: It could be a data depending error: a call now made to some method that sets the file.encoding. A library/IDE update. An IDE setting reset by some function key (terrifying). There are two consoles: in the IDEA and under Windows cmd. Maybe you are looking at cmd today, and yesterday at IDEA's console? Search for a setting of the encoding for IDEA

Comment: You are not using Grooviy scripts see [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59459)?

Comment: No, I'm not using Groovy scripts like this. I've been looking just IDEA's console. In fact, as said before, the problem has nothing to do with the console as it is related with string literals that are used as system paths to access local files. These are not working today and I've not changed any configuration parameter related to encoding. I'm taking a look at the git repository and see if it has something to do...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95951/discussion-between-joop-eggen-and-jgg).